# right and left sliding container with action FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, action, slide

I am trying to make a slider with action, sliding a container that when it reaches the right or left performs an action.

So far I haven't been able to find anything.

The gif shows what I want to do
[image: Application screen that I want to do]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/slider_button use thus package Or search "slide button package in flutter" on Google

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the following package: https://pub.dev/packages/action_slider
with the option `ActionSlider.dual()`